# "With/under the guidance of the world-class faculty"

Tags: grammar

I am writing my statement of purpose. Which is better: *under the guidance of the world-class faculty* or *with the guidance of the world-class faculty*?

Comment: The two are interchangeable. However, *under the guidance* connotes that you were more carefully supervised, which can be a good thing. *With the guidance* connotes more of a cooperative, equal relationship, wherein you had more autonomy. Do you want to imply you were carefully trained (I would want my surgeon to be very carefully trained) or that you were encouraged to blosom? (I would want an art student or writer to be treated this way.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is very useful. As I am applying to a  geography M.S. degree. I guess maybe "with" is better

Comment: If you are an English language learner rather than a native speaker or serious linguist, you might find our sister-site for [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com) to be a better fit for your questions than the current site, given that our charter here at ELU reads: “English Language & Usage Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for **linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts.”**

Answer (score 1):

*Under the guidance* and *with the guidance* are both correct.